# rxjs operators in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Is there any operator to achieve what the following `map` tries to do?

```
this.http.get(this.url)
         .pipe(map(data => {
             let results: object[] = new Array();
             data.forEach(function(d) {
                 let result = d['a'];
                 result['new_index'] = d['b'];
                 results.push(result);
             }
             retrun results;
         }));
```

`d['a']` is an object while `d['b']` is a string. The `new_index` key is new to each `result`.

Basically the original data contains quite a few fields out of which I only want 2 fields, one being the actual data of the object type, and the other an ID like field. I do not need any other fields. And I need to pull out that object data and insert the ID field into that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand a little bit Your data structure.

If `http.get` returns data like:

```js
[{
  a: {...},
  b: '...'
}]
```

then You just can use:

```js
this.http.get(this.url)
  .pipe(map(({a, b}) => {
    a.new_index = b;
    return a;
  }));
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3kfyruo0/);

But if Your data is really something like:

```js
[
  [{a: {...}, b: '...'}],
  [{a: {...}, b: '...'}],
]
```

(as You processing in Your example), so You can use [`[].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
this.http.get(this.url)
 .pipe(map(data =>
    data.map(({a, b}) => {
      a.new_index = b;
      return a;
    })
 ));
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/x0t7zha2/);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` Operator from Rxjs along with the `map` method on an array to do this:

Your implementation could be simplified like this:

```
this.http.get(this.url)
  .pipe(
    map((data: any[]) => data.map(
      (datum: any) => ({ 
        ...datum.a,
        new_index: datum.b
      })
    ))
  );
```